# Linear mixed model predictor distribution not fitting any of the options

Tags: r, mixed-model, bimodal

I am looking at the effect of beaver dams on water levels.

Can I use the `lme4` R package with a generalised or linear mixed model, and how?

My data doesn't seem to conform to any of the distribution options.

##### Data Variables

- mAODscale - water level data scaled to fluctuate around 0. It is made up
  of decimals. Fluctuate roughly around 1 and -1. Daily data for 3
  years.
- spi - a drought index that ranges from roughly 2 to -2. Also
  decimals. Monthly data for 3 years.
- siteTemp - water temperature at each dip well site. Decimals. Daily
  data for three years.
- baroTemp - air temperature for each location. Decimals. Daily data
  for three years.
- beaverEvent - before or after dam construction. Factor: 1 before, 2
  after.
- loc - dip well ID. Column made up of unique identifiers, e.g. 'B1', 'B2'..... 19 in total.
- mere - site ID. Unique identifier. 2 (possibly 3) in total - 'hatch' and 'chapel'.
- year - year of study. 1, 2 or 3.

##### Predictor Distribution

I'd like to look at a generalised linear mixed model, but I haven't been able to find the right distribution.

I have been following this [guide](https://ase.tufts.edu/bugs/guide/assets/mixed_model_guide.html).

I've also read that it’s only the residuals of the model that matter. These look more normal. Is this correct?

This is what the qq plot looks like. Any ideas? I'm new to this kind of modelling, so please explain everything in relatively simple terms.

```r
qqnorm(dfHatch$mAODscale)
```

##### Basic Model Run

This is my initial linear mixed model. However, I don't think my data is normally distributed, so I thought I needed a generalised linear mixed model.

Code:

```
mixed.lmer <- lmer(mAODscale~beaverEvent + spi + baroTemp + siteTemp + (1|loc), data=dfHatch)
mixed.lmer

plot(fitted(mixed.lmer), resid(mixed.lmer))
qqnorm(resid(mixed.lmer))
plot(density(resid(mixed.lmer)))
```

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: the residuals look reasonable to me.

Comment: @MattF. Good spot. Sorry I put in the wrong model results.

Comment: The q-q plot shows lack of fit in the upper quantiles which, in turn, suggests reversion to extreme value distributions, e.g., GEV, Weibull, and so on.

Comment: @MIke Hunter I've not come across them before. How would you suggest I alter my model to factor those kind of distributions in?

Comment: I don't code in R and have no suggestions. Otherwise, pursue relevant background reading on how EVT statistics works, e.g., https://www.google.com/books/edition/An_Introduction_to_Statistical_Modeling/SonbBwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=0 or the classic https://www.google.com/books/edition/Modelling_Extremal_Events/BXOI2pICfJUC?hl=en&gbpv=0  There exist R modules which handle them.

Comment: One displayed function call includes `year` as a predictor (evidently as numeric), but the table of results doesn't show a coefficient for it. The double peak in the distribution of model residuals suggests that there might be some categorical predictor missing from your model. Ignoring `year` as a predictor, or including it as a numeric linear predictor, might have led to that. Try including `year` in the model as a categorical predictor with 3 levels, and report the results. Please use the code `{}` tool on the toolbar, instead of images, to show model output.

Comment: The code and the output don't match: The variables `baroTemp` and `siteTemp` are missing.